# Bookmarklet to grab the current website address but without http://

Tags: url, ip-address, bookmarklet

The other day you were very helpful. Now I have another question. I have a bookmarklet to grab the current URL or I should say host name (without the `http://` part - which is ok) like:

```
javascript:q=(document.location.host); void(open('http://mysite.com/search.php?search='+location.host,'_self','resizable,location,menubar,toolbar,scrollbars,status'));
```

The problem is that this bookmarklet only grabs the host name like google.com and not the whole address like google.com/sub/page.htm. Is there any way I can left the `http://` part out and grab the remaining url?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that it's http (not https), then the following should work:

```
q=document.location.toString().substring(7);
```

Of course, you need to write `q` instead of `location.host` in what follows.

If you want to do it more robustly, use the [properties of the Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object) and concatenate the ones you want.